# Installing LogStash on windows

Tags: windows, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am millions of xml log files on a windows 2003 server. I am evaluating LogStash for searching through these xml files. Do we have a guide for installing and configuring LogStash\ElasticSearch\Kibana on a windows server? I searched on the internet but could not find much information about installing and configuring LogStash\ElasticSearch\Kibana on a windows server.

Comment: `Do we have a guide` - nobody knows, you will have to ask the other people you're referring to. Your teacher might have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-install-logstash-and-kibana-on-a-windows-server.34/

This is using windows IIS. 
Hope this will help.

[+]
Before download elk stack, make sure that install java SE, Ruby and Gem.

[Tutorial for downloading Ruby and Gem in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32957325/2962018)

Comment: i was able to get the ELK stack installed and working on my local machine. I was however unable to parse and get xml files indexed into elasticsearch. see here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parsing-xml-files-using-logstash/25372/11. I finally gave up.

Comment: @AjitGoel Sorry to hear that