# How to install Mongify on Windows

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I'm new on this trying to move data from sql server to mongodb, I found this tool but I don't know if it's working on Windows 7. It tells me that I need to run this:

gem install mongify

but I don't know where.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908708/installing-ruby-gem-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

I know that this was asked a long time ago and I dont know if someone has already sent you the answer but Mongify uses Ruby Gems.  This link can give you a good amount of information on how to install Ruby Gems [Installing Ruby Gem in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908708/installing-ruby-gem-in-windows). Once you install gems just follow the mongify tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Installed it on windows but in a docker container. It worked.

You can try this image : https://hub.docker.com/r/brisma/mongify/

Answer (score -2):

Mongify only exists on Linux, you can always try to install it on Windows, but I doubt it will ever work...