# Unable to Setup Ruby Gems on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

When I try to setup ruby gems on Windows 7 using http://rubyinstaller.org/:

```
ruby setup.rb
```

I get the following error

```
C:/rubygems-2.4.5/lib/rubygems.rb:1239:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gem::Specification (NameError)
    from setup.rb:32:in `require'
    from setup.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

How can I resolve this issue? I've tried using Ruby 2.1.5 and 1.9.3-p551.

**Edit**

```
C:\>ruby -version
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]-e:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `rsion' for main:Object (NameError)
```

The path environment variable is set to C:\Ruby21\bin.

Comment: In cmd, show us the output of `which ruby` and `which gem`

Comment: What's this setup.rb you're trying to run? Rubygems is part of the ruby standard library in ruby 2.0 and higher so you don't need to install it separately

Comment: Check if this link helps you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908708/installing-ruby-gem-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe James is trying to install the rubygems following the instructions provided in RubyGems.org

RubyInstaller had already installed rubygems for you so you don't need to to anything, you are ready to use Ruby!

If you are trying to create a gem, then you just have to follow the guide in http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/  but I believe you are just trying to use Ruby in Windows and if that is the case you don't need to create any gems neither install rubygems.

By the way, you have typed `ruby -version` but you should have either type `ruby -v` or `ruby --version` (double --) to see the version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting with rails, i d suggest using a different environment other than windows. You will continuously run into problems where gems cannot access your gnu compiler, things like unicorn server won't work. Download virtual box, and install fedora ssh server on it, then use putty to connect to your ruby environment. Set up vim with a rails plug in and u ll be good 2 go.