# Travis CI is failing but source code works fine?

Tags: php, github, travis-ci, github-api

I am facing build issue with Travis CI. I am new with Travis CI and as a basic step I have created a file .travis.yml into the GITHUB repository. But whenever I restart the build, it is failing.

I don't find any issue if I download the source code manually or install the framework using composer to run, it works perfect!! But not sure why Travis is failing.

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/sanjoydesk/cygniteframework) and [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/sanjoydesk/cygniteframework)

Will be grateful if anyone help me to find out the issue and fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all. The issue has been fixed.

Simple steps to setup:

1. Should have [GITHUB](https://github.com/) account. Register in [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) website using your GITHUB account.
2. Add `.travis.yml` file in root of your project. Add Travis as service in your repository settings page.

Follow simple steps for [Getting Started with Travis CI](http://www.appsntech.com/2015/10/travis-ci-continuous-integration-for-php-project.html). May help someone.

Comment: Hi, could you please include the steps that you used in the answer instead of just providing a link? That way this answer will be useful to others even if the link were to go bad some time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have run into GitHub's [API rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/). You might be able to circumvent this by using the `--prefer-source` flag when doing `composer install`.

Alternatively, you can specify a GitHub API token to access the GitHub API with "your" user without being affected by the rate limit for anonymous users. [This article](http://blog.champs-libres.coop/dev/2015/01/30/authenticate-against-github-travis-composer.html) describes how you can accomplish this -- it's in French, though, so I'll try to give a short summary (correct me if I read it wrong, my french is a bit out of practice):

1. Use the GitHub web UI to create a new API token ("Settings" -> "Personal access tokens" -> "Generate new Token"). Give your token the `public_repo` permission (you can also check `private_repo` to clone private repositories from Travis).
2. Include the token into your `.travis.yml`. Since that file is public, [encrypt the API key](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys) by running the following two commands on the command line:

   ```
   gem install travis
   travis encrypt GITHUB_COMPOSER_AUTH=123456789 --add
   ```
3. Configure Composer before doing `composer install`:

   ```
   composer config -g github-oauth.github.com $GITHUB_COMPOSER_AUTH
   composer install --dev --no-interaction
   ```
4. Voilà

Comment: Hi @helmbert i did changes in travis.yml as per your instructions, now it is throwing error as "The error was "could not found expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 8 column 1"." you can see here https://travis-ci.org/sanjoydesk/cygniteframework

Comment: @appsntech Oh, you included the two lines into the yaml file... I actually meant that you should run them on the command line *in order to edit the yaml file*. I'll adjust my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: I am using Windows. and not sure why we need to run gem install travis ? because travis will just validate the file and run if i am not wrong. Is there any possibilities to do the same on the go or using before_script:
  - gem install travis - travis encrypt GITHUB_COMPOSER_AUTH=123456789 --add likewise ?

Comment: You'll need the `travis` gem in order to be able to use the `travis` command-line tool (for encrypting the API key). And you can also [use Ruby and RubyGems on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908708/installing-ruby-gem-in-windows). :)

Comment: Oh, and I've noticed that you've included the API token *in plaintext* into your `.travis.yml`. I suggest you revoke your token and create a new one **at once** (there's a reason that it should be encrypted).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76935/discussion-between-appsntech-and-helmbert).