# trying to include sunlight congress gem in my project

Tags: ruby

So I am simply trying to run this code below with sunlight congress gem, but I seem to be doing something wrong. I am trying to include the gem in the project however something is off.

I am trying to implement this using RubyMine 7.1.2(if version matters), Ruby 2.2.2.
sunlight congress can be found here: https://github.com/sunlightlabs/ruby-sunlight.
Also, I am working on windows 8.1.

```
    require 'csv'

    require 'sunlight-congress'

    require 'erb'

    Sunlight::Congress.api_key = "e179a6973728c4dd3fb1204283aaccb5"

def neat_zip(zipcode)
  zipcode.to_s.rjust(5,"0")[0..4]
end
def legislator_by_zip(zipcode)
  Sunlight::Congress::Legislator.by_zipcode(zipcode)
end

def save_thank_you_letters(id,form_letter)
    Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists?("output")        
    filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"

    File.open(filename,'w') do |file|
      file.puts form_letter
      end

end

    puts "EventManager initialized."

    contents = CSV.open 'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol

    template_letter = File.read "form_letter.erb"

    erb_template = ERB.new template_letter

    contents.each do |row|

      id = row[0]

      name = row[:first_name]

      zipcode = neat_zip(row[:zipcode])

      legislators = legislator_by_zip(zipcode)

      form_letter = erb_template.result(binding)

      save_thank_you_letters(id,form_letter)
    end
```

I am getting this error:

```
C:\Ruby22\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)     C:/Ruby22/event_manager/sunlight-congress-master/lib/event_manager.rb
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sunlight-congress (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22/event_manager/sunlight-congress-master/lib/event_manager.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Do i simply have the path wrong? gem isnt installed?

Comment: ok making progress.         C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/congress-0.2.5/lib/congress.rb:10: warning: circular argument reference - key
        C:/Ruby22/event_m_2/event_manager.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sunlight (NameError)
         from -e:1:in `load'
         from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: im looking through congress module and i see there is an api_key function but it still seems to not see the gem? or maybe i am misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

You need to `gem install sunlight-congress`.

**Update:** Resources to install gems in Windows / RubyMine

- [Installing gems with RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/installing-and-uninstalling-gems.html)
- [Installing Ruby Gem in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908708/installing-ruby-gem-in-windows)
- http://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: I cant seem to understand where to do that in RubyMine. I did notice that in the instructions for sunlight congress

Comment: Updated with some help for that :)

Comment: I had looked at their resource before but it looked like a tutorial for a different version of RubyMine, the interface was different.  I will look at it all again.

Comment: The concept is surely still there somewhere, or use RubyInstaller, which seems like a popular choice.