# Can’t run ”gem install bundle’ in git bash terminal

Tags: git, bash, sinatra

I'm new to Web development with Sinatra.  I've been trying to run **bundle install** command in git-bash terminal, but it's says that:

[image: **bash: bundle:** command not found]

I've then tried to ***install bundler*** but then I'm kept getting this error:

[image: **bash: gem:** command not found]

I can't even run gem install bundler command in git-bash terminal. Please tell me what to do ??

I'm working on windows 7 x64bit system.

Comment: Have you installed ruby yet?

Comment: I did and it worked after installing **rubygem** :') Thankyou @BlackHatSamurai :')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that:

- [Ruby for Windows](https://rubyinstaller.org/) is installed
- your `%PATH%` is modified to reference `ruby` (`Advanced System Settings` / `Environment Variables` / `System Variables` /  `Path`: enter: `C:\Path\to\Ruby\bin;`)
- **[`rubygem`](https://rubygems.org/pages/download)** is installed. ([If you use `rubyinstaller`, that should be already the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18909228/6309))

Then open a new CMD session, and type `bash` (the bash from Git should open).
Then `ruby` should be available, including `gem`.

Comment: One thing, when I opened new **cmd** session and typed **bash**, it didn't work. It says **'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.** @VonC

Comment: Yes, you need your git/bin folder in your PATH